# Select a random chunk of 30 numbers from 200 numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Currently what I'm trying to do is get a chunk of 30 numbers from a set of 200. For example as this will be used with MySQL, I want to select 30 random images from a database of 200 images. I'd like to be able to have two numbers (a high and low) I could use in the limit statement that would return 30 rows of data like this: `SELECT * FROM 'images' LIMIT 20,50` or `SELECT * FROM 'images' LIMIT 10,40`. I know this probably sounds like a stupid question though my brain is just kinda stumped right now. All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Will the number of images grow significantly above 200? Is this data requested often?

Comment: Yes, it will grow as I'll be using `num_rows` in place of the 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `ORDER BY RAND()` to your query. It is "sufficiently" random.

```
 SELECT FOO FROM BAR ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30
```

Comment: order by rand() is an antipattern, so it shouldn't be used without thinking twice.

Comment: Would `SELECT 30 FROM 'images' ORDER BY RAND();` select 30 random images from the images table then?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Brad. Answered from my mobile so limited editing options.

Comment: No problem.  @scjosh, You need a `LIMIT` clause.  `SELECT somefields FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ORDER BY RAND()` is considered an antipattern because you're forcing the database to perform a full table scan and expensive sort operation.

To benefit from query caching, you could make a hybrid solution like:

```
// take all image ids
$keys = $db->query('SELECT image_id FROM images')->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

// pick 30
$random_keys = join(',', array_rand(array_flip($keys), 30));

// query those images only
$values = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id IN ($random_keys)")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The above query for the keys can be cached in PHP, so it can be used for more frequent requests. **However**, when your table becomes in the range of 100k or more, I would suggest creating a separate table with the image ids in a randomized order that you can join against the images table. You can populate this once or a few times per day using the `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Comment: Would this be faster in the long run then using `$query = "SELECT * FROM 'images' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;";` My only concern is that when the database grows larger the query will take longer to execute.

Comment: @scjosh Using `ORDER BY RAND()` will force a full table scan and manual sorting, so if your table grows big and you need to access this information often (i.e. at every request) my approach will be better, because you can cache the image ids in php.

Comment: @scjosh When your table grows beyond a few 100k rows, you should look into creating a separate table with random keys that you can join against the images table; you can build the table every day using the order by rand(), because it only runs once :)

Comment: That's a great idea. For now I'll just use the order by rand() but in the future I'll just have a separate table like you said and marquee those random images.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using PHP's `array_rand()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Put whatever you want to choose from in an array, and let it pick 20 entries for you.  Then, you can use whatever file names you want without having to rely on them being in numerical order.

Comment: Also note that this is a PHP solution.  That's what your question is tagged as.  If you instead wanted an SQL solution, go with Burhan's example.